# Network card won't identify network with regular cable after using crossover

Tags: router, home-networking

I have a laptop: HP Pavilion g6 1212-sq (kind of old), a router in one room and a switch connected to the router in other room. 
Cables:
- a crossover cable, the owner is a friend of mine (f);
- two regular/conventional cables which I own (m1, m2);

Cables m1&m2 were working w/o issues connected to laptop and switch. After connecting cable f to switch and laptop, network card cannot identify the network anymore if I'm using m1 or m2 (Windows 8 or Ubuntu 14.04).

What I tried:
- connected m1, m2 & f to Mac mini (Mid 2012) and all were working;
- reset router; reset router to factory settings;
- reboot laptop;
- disable/enable LAN;
- reinstall Ethernet driver;
- Wi-Fi in Ubuntu is working;(in Windows have lots of problems with Wi-Fi;
- m1/m2 connected directly router & laptop still not working;

What caused this issue?
How can I get working m1 & m2 cables for my laptop?

Comment: Do you see any link lights on either the laptop or the router when you connect using the regular cables?

Comment: Both switch and router recognizes the laptop(a green light is visible). On laptop a white and a blinking orange led are lighting. Like the laptop is connected to the lan, but in fact the software tells me that it cannot establish the connection.

Comment: Yesterday I was searching for a solution for this problem. I've found something Auto-MDI. Is it possible that my Mac mini has auto-mdi and detect internet connection immediately and the laptop doesn't have it? If so, how can I tell my laptop to use MDI and not MDI-X? (what I've tried so far didn't worked)

Comment: First, log into your router using a second system and see if a link really is established.  That will help isolate if this is a software or hardware issue

Comment: @ernie I don't think it's the hardware. I do have internet connection using crossover cable. Checked connection, says that there was a connection today from laptop; can't tell if it was with crossover cable or regular one. The log doesn't help me either. Did reset DHCP Server but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ernie you were right, might be a harware issue and it is. The crossover port fits exactly, the regular ones don't. If I'm carefully connecting the cable in ethernet port, it idenfies the network. Thank you for your time!